# Python - difference between os.access and os.path.exists?

Tags: python, operating-system, module

```
def CreateDirectory(pathName):
    if not os.access(pathName, os.F_OK):
        os.makedirs(pathName)
```

versus:

```
def CreateDirectory(pathName):
    if not os.path.exists(pathName):
        os.makedirs(pathName)
```

I understand that os.access is a bit more flexible since you can check for RWE attributes as well as path existence, but is there some subtle difference I'm missing here between these two implementations?

Comment: If the docs are to be believed, it is even more subtle than what the answers say. The `os.F_OK` mode is specifically for testing existence, not permissions; while for `os.path.exists()`: "On some platforms, this function may return False if permission is not granted to execute os.stat() on the requested file, even if the path physically exists." The [FreeBSD man pages](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=access&sektion=2) say `access` is cheaper than `stat` for testing existence.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Better to just catch the exception rather than try to prevent it. There are a zillion reasons that makedirs can fail

```
def CreateDirectory(pathName):
    try:
        os.makedirs(pathName)
    except OSError, e:
        # could be that the directory already exists
        # could be permission error
        # could be file system is full
        # look at e.errno to determine what went wrong
```

To answer your question, `os.access` can test for permission to read or write the file (as the logged in user). `os.path.exists` simply tells you whether there is something there or not. I expect most people would use `os.path.exists` to test for the existence of a file as it is easier to remember.

Answer (score 3):

`os.access` tests if the path can be accessed by the current user
`os.path.exists` checks if the path does exist. `os.access` could return `False` even if the path exists.